# JFrame getLayout method does not return set cardLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, cardlayout

I am setting a CardLayout as the a JFrame's layout but when I call the getLayout method a border layout is returned.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SSCCE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        frame.setLayout(cl);
        System.out.println(cl);
        System.out.println(frame.getLayout());

    }
}
```

This is printed to console:

```
java.awt.CardLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
java.awt.BorderLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JFrame redirects the setLayout() to content pane. That's source snippet

```
public void setLayout(LayoutManager manager) {
    if(isRootPaneCheckingEnabled()) {
        getContentPane().setLayout(manager);
    }
    else {
        super.setLayout(manager);
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the *many* reasons that it is a good idea to make the GUI in a `JPanel` then add that panel (alone) to the content pane.