# Can't set JFrame layout

Tags: java, jframe

I have tried setting the layout of a `JFrame`, and it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible?

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
System.out.println(frame.getLayout().toString());
```

The output I get from this is:

```
java.awt.BorderLayout[hgap=0,vgap=0]
```

Comment: Its related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376254/jframe-getlayout-method-does-not-return-set-cardlayout

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a minor hierarchal issue associated with `JFrame`.

`JFrame` isn't actually a single component, it's a composite component.  This means it contains a number of layers, which make up the actual structure of the window, for example...

[image: JFrame's rootpane]

Prior to 1.5 (I think), you would have been required to use `JFrame#getContentPane#setLayout` and `JFrame#getContentPane#getLayout`, which, as you can imagine, is tedious to type.

Since 1.5, you can now call `JFrame#setLayout` directly and the call will be forwarded directly to the `contentPane` instead.  The problem is, `getLayout` still needs to return the layout manager used by the frame itself, which is the hole you've found yourself in.

If, instead, you use ...

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
System.out.println(frame.getContentPane().getLayout());
```

It will print `java.awt.FlowLayout[hgap=5,vgap=5,align=center]`

Yes, I know, it's not entirely obvious, which is why the original API required you to be specific about your intent, calling `getContentPane` directly, rather then passing the call on automatically